# Test case for create new acc Gmail form--unable to select "Month" drop down

Tags: selenium

I am a newbie in selenium webdriver,
I am writing a test case- "Create new account in gmail" unable to select month..

Here is code i used:

```
    driver.findElement(By.id("link-signup")).click();
    WebElement element =driver.findElement(By.id("BirthMonth"));
    Select mSelection = new Select(element);
    mSelection.selectByVisibleText("July");
```

i am getting error:: 
Unexpected Tagname exception :Element should have been select but was span

--i didnt find any select tag in html code.. how to resolve this

html code::

```
<label id="month-label" class="month">
<span id="BirthMonth" class=" " aria-invalid="false">
<div class="goog-inline-block goog-flat-menu-button jfk-select goog-flat-menu-button-hover goog-flat-menu-button-focused" role="listbox" style="-moz-user-select: none;" aria-expanded="false" tabindex="0" aria-haspopup="true" title="" aria-activedescendant=":0">
<div id=":0" class="goog-inline-block goog-flat-menu-button-caption" role="option" aria-setsize="12" aria-posinset="0">Month</div>
<div class="goog-inline-block goog-flat-menu-button-dropdown" aria-hidden="true"/>
</div>
<div class="goog-menu goog-menu-vertical" style="-moz-user-select: none; visibility: visible; left: 0px; top: -107.133px; display: none;" role="listbox" aria-haspopup="true">
<div id=":1" class="goog-menuitem" role="option" style="-moz-user-select: none;">
<div id=":2" class="goog-menuitem" role="option" style="-moz-user-select: none;">
<div id=":3" class="goog-menuitem" role="option" style="-moz-user-select: none;">
<div id=":4" class="goog-menuitem" role="option" style="-moz-user-select: none;">
<div id=":5" class="goog-menuitem" role="option" style="-moz-user-select: none;">
<div id=":6" class="goog-menuitem" role="option" style="-moz-user-select: none;">
<div id=":7" class="goog-menuitem" role="option" style="-moz-user-select: none;">
<div id=":8" class="goog-menuitem" role="option" style="-moz-user-select: none;">
<div id=":9" class="goog-menuitem" role="option" style="-moz-user-select: none;">
<div id=":a" class="goog-menuitem" role="option" style="-moz-user-select: none;">
<div id=":b" class="goog-menuitem" role="option" style="-moz-user-select: none;">
<div id=":c" class="goog-menuitem" role="option" style="-moz-user-select: none;">
</div>
<input id="HiddenBirthMonth" type="hidden" name="BirthMonth"/>
</span>
</label>
```

--thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you did not find any select tag over there, and you want to select a month: You can click on the month element and select the month.

```
//Click on the month listbox
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='BirthMonth']/div")).click();

//Select the february month
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id=':2']/div")).click();
```

Every month has different id over there, so you can select the month you want.

---

You can also get all months over there in a list and select the one you need

```
   List<WebElement> months = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@class='goog-menuitem']"));
        for (int i=0; i<months.size(); i++){
            if (months.get(i).getText().trim().equals("July"))
                months.get(i).click();
        }
```

Above code will select July from the list

Comment: Hi, i am trying to scroll down page:
when i used code : 
 ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("window.scrollBy("+x+","+y+")", "");
its working fine .



But when i declare javascript executor initially and use object then its giving Null pointer exception 
code:
JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
 jse.executeScript("window.scrollBy("+x+","+y+")", "");

i didnt understand why is it giving exception.?

--Thanks in advance